# Convergence of inner product sequence $\langle \vec{x}_k, \vec{y}_k\rangle$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, solution-verification, continuity

Let $\{\vec{x_k}\}, \{\vec{y_k}\}$ be two sequences which converge to $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$, respectively. I want to show that the inner product sequence $\langle \vec{x}_k, \vec{y}_k\rangle$ converges to $\langle \vec{a}, \vec{b}\rangle$. Unfortunately, I'm stuck. Here's how I begin my proof:

$|\langle \vec{x}_k, \vec{y}_k\rangle-\langle \vec{a}, \vec{b}\rangle|\le |\|x_k\|\|y_k\|-\langle \vec{a}, \vec{b}\rangle|$, then I can proceed to manipulating the inequality, but the problem is that the $\langle \vec{a}, \vec{b}\rangle$ always remains. Please give me a hint!

Another approach I was thinking about: first prove that the inner product is continuous and then take the limit of the inner product inside the inner product (as $k\to\infty$). However, is the inner product function really continuous? Trying to prove this involves dealing with a function of two variables, such as $f(\vec{x},\vec{y}):\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}\to\mathbb{R}$, defined as $f(\vec{x},\vec{y})=\vec{x_k}^T\vec{y_k}$. But this is just for the dot product, not for the general inner product. Otherwise, yes, the dot product is continuous.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: write $$\langle x_k, y_k\rangle -\langle a, b\rangle = \langle x_k, y_k\rangle -\langle x_k, b\rangle +\langle x_k, b\rangle- \langle a, b\rangle$$

Comment: Using Thomas's hint, you just need to apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @Thomas, I'm still left with the $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ terms after the minus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
|\langle x_k,y_k\rangle-\langle a,b\rangle|&\leq|\langle x_k,y_k\rangle-\langle x_k,b\rangle|+|\langle x_k,b\rangle-\langle a,b\rangle|\\
&=|\langle x_k,y_k-b\rangle|+|\langle x_k-a,b\rangle|\\
&\leq||x_k||\cdot||y_k-b||+||x_k-a||\cdot||b||\\
&\leq M\cdot||y_k-b||+||x_k-a||\cdot||b||
\end{align*}

( $x_n$ it is bounded because it converges). For the inequality I used Cauchy-Schwarz. The last quantity of the above inequality goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Oh, I see my missing link... Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome.